# How do I use Firebug to find out how many CSS files are being used on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I recently came across this error in IE9 that says :-

"The maximum number os style sheet on this page(31) has been reached. The browser will not load these excessive style sheets...."

Now on my website's master page, I have placed this Telerik control "[RadStyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html)" which is supposed to combine the style sheets if I am not wrong. I thought would solve the issue but no results.

Someone please point me towards the right direction. How do I find out the number of CSS files and how should I really use the [RadStyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html) to make my aspx pages load faster.

Comment: IE still has that limit, even at version 9? That is hilarious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebug you can:

- open CSS tab to see all the files with their content
- open Net tab to see all the requests and find your CSS files there (filter using CSS button in the toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

you can look at the net tab in firebug to see all the request for css files